# Where is the Kurdish principality of Botan?

Tags: setting, ahmad-khani, kurmanji-kurdish-language, mem-and-zin

The classical Kurdish story of Mem and Zin (which I'm [reading online in Salah Saadalla's translation](https://archive.org/details/AhmedKhaniMemAndJinTrans.BySalahSaadalla/page/n43/mode/2up)) appears to be set in a principality called Botan, whose prince (Zin's brother) rules from the town of Jizir:

> His throne was in Jizir<sup>19</sup> and his star was rising
> His luck was strong and his position was praisworthy
>
> He ruled over the Turk, the Arab and the Persian
> He was famous as the Prince of Botan
>
> <sup>19</sup> <sub>Jizir: the capital of the principality of Botan. Now a town in South East Turkey.</sub>

Now I've tried to search for Jizir and Botan, but the only references I've found online have been back to the story of Mem and Zin, or like [this article](http://ensani.ir/file/download/article/1590463669-10222-2020-1-9.pdf) to other pieces of Kurdish literature ("*The land of Jizir and Botan, which is the land of Kurdistan*").

What is the setting of *Mem and Zin*? **Was Botan a real Kurdish principality, and if so where and when?** Or is it something invented for the story, a fictional Kurdish nation to instil pride in Kurdish listeners?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By searching online for ‘Botan’ plus ‘Kurds’, I arrived at the following [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bohtan) article:

> Bohtan (also Buhtan, Bokhti) was a medieval Kurdish principality in the Ottoman Empire
> centered on the town of Jazirah ibn 'Omar (modern Cizre also known as
> Cizîra Botan (Jazira Botan)) in southeastern Anatolia.